# How to draw a dragged and droppped image on to a canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I drag and drop images on to a canvas using below code . Can someone please tell me how to draw it on a canvas? Thanks in advance.Earlier my canvas used to be a div and I used to append img to that div and it worked.But now I want it to be drawn to a canvas.

```
function dropb(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  const dt = ev.dataTransfer;
  const files = dt.files;

  handleFilesb(files);
}


function handleFilesb(files) {
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const file = files[i];

    if (!file.type.startsWith('image/')) {
      continue
    }

    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.className = "my_image";
    img.setAttribute("width", "300px");
    img.setAttribute("height", "300px");

    img.classList.add("obj");
    img.file = file;

    document.getElementById("area_c"); // canvas
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10); // this line is not working 

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
      return function(e) {
        aImg.src = e.target.result;
      };
    })(img);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}



             <div style="display:flex">
                           <canvas id ="area_c" style="width:300px;height:300px;border:3px solid black;z-index:1"  ondrop="dropb(event)"  ondragover="myfkb(event)"   >

                           </canvas>


                            <div  id ="area_c2" style="width:300px;height:300px;border:3px solid black;z-index:1"  >

                            </div>

                            <div >

                                <input type="button"   value="Crop" 
                             onclick="crop()">

                            </div>

                   </div>
```

Comment: Please share the HTML code as well so we can get a better idea of the matter.

Comment: I just did , please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ctx.drawImage(img)` comes before `img.src`... There is no way your image gets drawn.

You need to wait until it loads, and that will be only after the FileReader `onload` event fired, and even after the `img`'s `onload` fires:

```
img.onload = e => {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
};
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
  return function(e) {
    aImg.src = e.target.result;
  };
})(img);
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

But you don't need the FileReader here, [use a blob URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) instead:

```
img.onload = e => {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
};
img.src = URL.createObjetURL(file);
```

```js
const c = document.getElementById("area_c");
c.ondragover = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
}
c.ondrop = dropb;
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function dropb(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  const dt = ev.dataTransfer;
  const files = dt.files;

  handleFilesb(files);
}


function handleFilesb(files) {
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const file = files[i];

    if (!file.type.startsWith('image/')) {
      continue
    }

    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.className = "my_image";
    img.setAttribute("width", "300px");
    img.setAttribute("height", "300px");

    img.classList.add("obj");
    img.file = file;
    img.onload = e => {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
    };
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<canvas id="area_c">


</canvas>
```

Comment: Well it is not working , I added the img.onload = e => {  ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
}; part .Btw why is your syntax different. Is it possible to not change the complete code because your code seems very confusing to me .I am new to this .

Comment: I got it to work , Thank you so much . Can you tell me why the image has not got resized to the set attributes

Comment: You need to use the fourth and fifth parameters of [`drawImage(img, x, y, width, height)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) to make it resize your image. It doesn't really care about the container, only about the intrinsic size of the media to be drawn.